# CSS3 Background Animation Moving Content

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

Here's the CSS:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://puu.sh/hzABm/3768f6abbb.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;

}
```

Which is for the following HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="innercontent">
<p>This content is moving, why?</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I am trying to animate the body background to be clouds moving, but the entire page is scrolling, along with the background. For example, if you were to run the above code, the text "This content is moving, why?" would be moving. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please, create working code example with http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Based on the code you have shown in question, the content should not be scrolling. Seems like there must be something else in your code which is causing it. Please create a demo.

Answer (score 1):

I show you an example working with your code:

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
   from { background-position: 0 0; }
   to { background-position: 100% 0; }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
   from { background-position: 0 0; }
   to { background-position: 100% 0; }
  }
  @-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
   from { background-position: 0 0; }
   to { background-position: 100% 0; }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
   from { background-position: 0 0; }
   to { background-position: 100% 0; }
  }
  #animate-area { 
   width: 560px; 
   height: 400px; 
   background-image: url(http://puu.sh/hzABm/3768f6abbb.png);
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;

   animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
   -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
  }
```

```html
<html><head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="animate-area"><p>This content is moving, why?</p></div>
</body></html>
```